# In Microsoft Access 2013, how do I access the username of the current ODBC connection?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am building a system in Microsoft Access 2013 that is using MySQL as the backend. I would like to have a form where the username of the user currently logged in to the MySQL database is the default value for an input field. I tried using the CurrentUser() function to do this, but that seems to always return "Admin".

So I guess there are really two questions here:

1. Is there a way to access the username of the user logged in to the MySQL server from within Access 2013?
2. If not, how do I control what the username is for CurrentUser()? It's very important in this system that I am able to differentiate between different users of the system and that not everyone simply shows up as "Admin".

It's possible there is a much better way to accomplish what I'm asking and I don't even know the right question to ask, and if that's the case please do let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you specifically looking for the username of the ODBC connection?  If you just want to know the windows user name, you can try `msgbox (Environ$("Username"))`.

Comment: I was thinking that I would set up my users with different usernames/passwords to connect to the MySQL server, and the Access DB would be customized based on their username and corresponding rights. Basically I want to figure out some form of user management that doesn't rely on SharePoint, which I'm trying to set up but is proving to be extremely difficult due to lack of experience and resources.

Answer (score 2):

Create a "pass through" query in Access which uses the ODBC connection to MySQL, and ask MySQL for the name of the current user.

```sql
SELECT CURRENT_USER();
```

That query will be executed as is (meaning the Access db engine is not involved) at the server, and the result from the query is then available in Access.

The VBA `CurrentUser()` function retrieves the Access security account name.  Unless you're using ULS (user level security), which is only available with the older MDB database format, the security account will always be *"Admin"*.  So it's not generally useful, and is definitely not useful for what you need here.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! I feel like I'm pretty close, and I created the pass through query like you described. However, every time I run it, it prompts me to select the data source and then I have to put in my username and password. When I do this, it just returns the username that I use to log in at that point, but what I really want to do is have it return the username that was used to initiate the connection to the linked tables originally. Is there any way to do that? I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Open the pass-thru in Design View, then open the query's property sheet.  Check the "ODBC Connect Str" property, and compare it with what you have for your ODBC link tables.  If they're the same, I don't understand why you are asked for that information repeatedly.

Comment: Getting closer and closer. The ODBC Connect Str was totally different from what was listed in my linked tables, so I updated it to have everything up to the port info and now it doesn't prompt me anymore for connection info. My pass through query is called CurrentUser, and the SQL is "SELECT CURRENT_USER() AS Expr1;", and in my form I have the default value set to "=[CurrentUser]![Expr1]", but when I try to add a new record it just shows up as #Error. Any idea what I'm doing wrong now? Thanks so much for your help so far!

Comment: Look into `DLookup()`, perhaps `=DLookup("Expr1", "the name you gave your pass thru query")`

Comment: DLookup didn't work for me either. I also tried creating a local query that took the values from the pass through query and then referencing it as the default value, but that failed. Do I have to specify which row should be considered the default value somehow? The values come through if I change the text box to a combo box and use the pass through query as the row source. I can unbind that combo box, create a new text box that is bound to the desired field, and make it get the default value by doing default value "=[combobox].ItemData[0]", but I can't figure out how to do this directly.

Comment: Oh wait, I can make the default value of the combo box the value returned from the query by doing [combobox].ItemData[0], and that will work just fine for my purposes! There's probably a more elegant way, but this should work for now.

Comment: OK.  If you want to try something else, make a new question and show us what the pass-thru query returns and include details about what you want to do with it.